# Fix youtube embed clipping

Tags: html, css, embed

I want to have a youtube video as an embed on my website, but it is clipping through the content.

Image : [image]

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  
}

.container {
  min-height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column; 
}
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 23px;
  border-style: solid;
  text-shadow: #000 0px 0px 1px,   #000 0px 0px 1px,   #000 0px 0px 1px, #000 0px 0px 1px,   #000 0px 0px 1px,   #000 0px 0px 1px, #000 0px 0px 1px, #000 0px 0px 1px;
  margin-top: 215px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
.menu{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.aboutp{
    width: 1000px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin:auto;
}
.mario{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 20vw;
    margin: auto;
}
.topContent{
    background-color: red;
    height: 10vh;
    width: 70vw;
    max-width: 700px;
    max-height: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 1.5vh;
    border-style: solid;
}
.mainContent{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto 50px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    font-size: 1.5vh;
    max-width: 768px;

}

.left {
    width:15%;
    float: left;
}

.right{
    width:15%;
}

.center {
    width:65%;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-style: solid;
}

.bottom {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 768px;
    max-height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    border-style: solid;
}

.bottom a {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
    padding: 2vh;
    width: 768px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2vh;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    text-shadow: #000 0px 0px 1px,   #000 0px 0px 1px,   #000 0px 0px 1px, #000 0px 0px 1px,   #000 0px 0px 1px,   #000 0px 0px 1px, #000 0px 0px 1px, #000 0px 0px 1px;

}
```

```html
<div class = "topContent">
        <h1>Game History</h1>
    </div>
<div class = "mainContent">
        <div class="left">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JO86YAiYFjc" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
            <p class="aboutp1">
                 bunch of text
            </p>
            <p class="aboutp2"> 
                      bunch of text
                <img src="../resources/mario-super.gif" alt="Mario Gif" class="mariogif">
                      bunch of text
            </p>

            <p class="aboutp3">
                  bunch of text
                         </p>
            <p class="aboutp4">      
                            bunch of text
                            </p>
            <p class="aboutp5">
                  bunch of text
                                 </p>
                
        </div>
        <div class="right"><img src="../resources/mario.png" alt="Mario Image" class="mario"></div>

    
    <div class="bottom">
        </div>
    
</div>
```

You can see in the picture how the embed video clips behind the text. I want it to be on the left side of the screen and to not push away the other content.

I want the embed file to be in the middle of the left side of the whole screen.

Comment: The `<iframe width="560" height="315">` has a height/width set superceding all CSS, you need to remove those values and create CSS rules to make it resize. Maybe work with `z-index` too.

Comment: Yes but how do I move it to the left? @RenevanderLende

Answer (score 0):

For Showing content above another use CSS z-index Property.

it will put your content above another code.

```css
    .mainContent{
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto 50px;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        font-size: 1.5vh;
        max-width: 768px;
        z-index: 2;
    }
```

Comment: Yes but how do I move it to the left?

Comment: @Symet3 can you tell me clearly what you really want

Comment: @T 7  I want it like this. The youtube video is on the left. https://imgur.com/a/eWe4ltq